# Int cannot represent non-integer value: "4"

Tags: graphql, hasura

The error obviously makes sense. We are passing strings for Int value, but this used to work just fine. This has quite big implication on our code.

Example of error:
[image: Example of error]

I also have 2 environment running with same Hasura version. On one of these this error is not occurring. As far as I know we haven't touched these environment in at least 2 months.

Hasura about info:

[image: Hasura about info]

Does anyone have a solution or any inside on the issue?

Comment: i've tested this in server v2.2 and the API accepts a stringified `Int` (despited the GraphiQL warning). hmm—are your DB's identical in both instances? i wonder if something like a foreign-key constraint might cause the rejection...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some more investigating I found the culprit. It was the graphql of the remote schema not Hasura itself.

It uses PHP Lighthouse -> webonyx/graphql and something must of changed for IntType and FloatType.
I fixed it by introducing custom scalars that do accept strings.

I assumed it was Hasura at first because the remote schema didn't receive an update in 2 months.

I guess we just didn't noticed.